# can't interact with newly appended div JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is my code:

```
<p id = "id_2">click</a>


<div class = "test_1" id = "id_2" style = "display:none;">
    <p>test_div_1</p>
</div>


<div class = "test_2" style="display:none;">
    <p>test_div_2</p>
</div>




<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#id_2").click(function(){
        $(".test_1").show()
        $("body").append("<p id = 'test_p'>test</p>")
    });
    $("#test_p").click(function(){
            $(".test_2").show()
    });
});
</script>
```

basically what I'm trying to do is: when you click `<p id = "id_2">click</a>`

it'll show `<div class = "test_1">` and append another paragraph which is what I did here:

```
$("#id_2").click(function(){
    $(".test_1").show()
    $("body").append("<p id = 'test_p'>test</p>")

});
```

and afterwards when you click on the newly appended paragraph `<p id = 'test_p'>test</p>` it should show another div which should be:

```
   $("#test_p").click(function(){
        $(".test_2").show()
});
```

but it doesn't.
how do we get around this? 
I'm still trying to wrap my head around web development.
I do know that the appended it's temporary because a page refresh would erase it unless the appended data was saved on the server.
I wonder if that has anything to do with that?.

because facebook's and twitters posting feature is intriguing 
I know it uses ajax to post the info to the server without a page refresh but how is it able to interact with a div or element that's just been newly appended?

Comment: Use event delegation. `$('body').on('click', '#test_p', function() { ... })`

Comment: how is that different from doing `("#test_p").click(function(){}` I've read in the docs that click calls `on` the way you suggested

Comment: Read [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)